# Computed array with KnockoutJS - throwing not defined error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got a viewmodel that looks like this:

```
    var viewModel = {

        name: results.name,
        members: ko.observableArray([]),
        users: ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(members(), function (item) {
                return (item.type == 'User');
            });
        }),
        groups: ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(members(), function (item) {
                return (item.type == 'Group');
            });
        })
    };
```

However, I'm getting an error on the `computed` part:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: members is not defined

Which is true- at the time the viewModel is declared, members contains nothing.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by `members()` you mean the second property on your object:

```
var viewModel = {
    name: results.name,
    members: ko.observableArray([])
};

viewModel.users = ko.computed(function () {
     return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.members(), function (item) {
         return (item.type == 'User');
     });
 });
viewModel.groups = ko.computed(function () {
     return ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.members(), function (item) {
         return (item.type == 'Group');
     });
 });
```

Note that:

- You cannot reference another property of the same object inside a literal definition. That's why I split the definition into 3 parts.
- `members()` was replaced with `viewModel.members()`.

Comment: viewModel.member is really function because it is obserableArray. So it should be viewModel.member().

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes - I kept it as viewModel.members() (although i see you have edited it now)

Comment: Thanks @Artem, updated accordingly. I don't know much about knockout.